# SQL Query with specific Order By format

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table with following values

```
    OperationCode   OperationDesc   OperationOrder
    Repl        Remove          1
    R&I         Remove          1
    Ovrh        Remove          1
    Refn        Prep            1
    Repl        Replace         2
    R&I         Install         2
    Ovrh        Install         2
    Refn        Paint           2
```

I want to write a query to get following result order. See in OperationOrder Column

```
    OperationCode   OperationDesc   OperationOrder
    Repl            Remove      1
    Repl            Replace     2
    R&I             Remove      1
    R&I             Install     2
    Ovrh            Remove      1
    Ovrh            Install     2
    Refn            Prep        1
    Refn            Paint       2
```

I am using sql server 2005.

Comment: You want 4 spaces in front of the OperationDesc? Ok this is pretty simple, but why do you need to do this? Maybe there is a better way than formatting in your SQL (what are you outputting this to?)

Comment: Are you after `ORDER BY OperationID` or `ORDER BY OperationCode,OperationOrder`?

Comment: Also, I can see he wants to `ORDER BY` first column

Comment: No I want the only order not space

Comment: Reading some SQL doc would have cost you less time than formatting this question...

Comment: @Sharad A simple web search would have given you the answer, and it would have been less effort than writing a question and expecting you get an answer here.

Comment: Can you give more info - I'm guessing you want to order by OperationCode and OperationOrder and then have an incrementing field?

Comment: @Sharad : Now see my Answer.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544255/need-a-sql-query-to-get-specific-order/17544418#17544418) is same Question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Here is SQLFiddel Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7a1f6/1)**

Below is the Sample Query Which You can try

```
SELECT * FROM temp
ORDER BY 
CASE OperationCode 
     WHEN 'Repl' THEN 1
     WHEN 'R&I' THEN 2
     WHEN 'Ovrh' THEN 3
     WHEN 'Refn' THEN 4
END, OperationOrder
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to use `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT OperationId, OperationCode, OperationDesc, OperationOrder
FROM YourTable
ORDER By OperationCode ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OperationCode, OperationOrder) as OperationId, 
    OperationCode, 
    OperationDesc, 
    OperationOrder 
FROM SomeTable 
ORDER BY OperationCode, OperationOrder
```

as it looks like your OperationId has changed order in each result set and therefore must be an auto-generated number

Answer (score 0):

IF you need a fixed order of the "OperationCode" a.k.a:
**Repl < R&I < Ovrh < Refn**

```
SELECT *  
FROM YourTable  
ORDER By   
    OperationCode = 'Repl' DESC,  
    OperationCode = 'R&I'  DESC,  
    OperationCode = 'Ovrh' DESC,  
    OperationCode = 'Refn' DESC
```

"OperationCode = 'Repl'" will return a  0/1 and if you order it with DESC this will put,
**'Repl'** values first end everything else after that.

Comment: This is (My)SQL syntax.  @RJ1990 got the proper working example for MSSQL.