# Sql case with case Order by

Tags: mysql, sql, case

```
select id, username, email, 
 case
 when username = email then 'true'
 else 'false' 
 end 
 from users
```

Is there a simple way to do `when username = email then 'true' as order_col` or `from users where case = true`

The question is can you wrap case in `AS case`and then order it or use Where statement on that case.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Want you order your result set on equals of username and email?

Comment: So you want to use the column alias (you have not specified) in the `ORDER BY` and in the `WHERE`-clause?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543771/i-need-a-sql-query-to-get-a-specific-format-as-given-in-example/17543847#17543847

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 select id, username, email, 
             case when username = email 
                  then 'true'
                  else 'false' 
             end as usr_is_email
 from users
 order by usr_is_email
```

Comment: _"use Where statement on that case"_ ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the alias in the `ORDER BY` but not in the `WHERE`, so this works:

```
SELECT id, username, email, 
       CASE 
         WHEN username = email THEN 'true' 
         ELSE 'false' 
       end AS UserNameIsEmail 
FROM   users 
ORDER  BY UserNameIsEmail DESC,
          username ASC
```

If you want it to use in the `WHERE` either repeat it or use a sub-query:

```
SELECT id, username, email, usernameisemail 
FROM  (SELECT id, 
              username, 
              email, 
              CASE 
                WHEN username = email THEN 'true' 
                ELSE 'false' 
              end AS UserNameIsEmail 
       FROM   users)X 
WHERE  X.usernameisemail = 'true' 
ORDER  BY username ASC
```