# how to make the data sorts like this on sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've a data that looks like this

```
| FormCode | Description          | MenuPath    |
+----------+----------------------+-------------+
|   PY     | Payroll              |             |
|   PD     | Personal Development |             | 
|   EM     | EmployeeMaster       |     PY      |
|   EB     | EmployeeBank         |     PY      |
|   ED     | EmployeeData         |     PY      |
| Report   | Report               |     PY      |
|  Badge   | Badge Report         |  PY/Report  |
| Process  | Process              |     PY      |
|  Bonus   | Bonus Component      |    PY/ED    | 
|Preference| Preference           |     PY      |
|   Tax    | Tax Result           |    PY/ED    |
|FinalBonus| FinalBonus           | PY/ED/Bonus |
| Annual   | Annual Process       | PY/Process  |
|BonusbyCC | Bonus by Cost Centre | PY/ED/Bonus |
| Period   | Period               |PY/Preference|
```

I want this data sort to be like this below.

```
| FormCode | Description          | MenuPath    |
+----------+----------------------+-------------+
|   PY     | Payroll              |             |
|   EB     | EmployeeBank         |     PY      |
|   ED     | EmployeeData         |     PY      |
|  Bonus   | Bonus Component      |    PY/ED    |
|BonusbyCC | Bonus by Cost Centre | PY/ED/Bonus |
|FinalBonus| FinalBonus           | PY/ED/Bonus |
|   Tax    | Tax Result           |    PY/ED    |
|   EM     | EmployeeMaster       |     PY      |
|Preference| Preference           |     PY      |
| Period   | Period               |PY/Preference|
| Process  | Process              |     PY      |
| Annual   | Annual Process       | PY/Process  |
| Report   | Report               |     PY      |
|  Badge   | Badge Report         |  PY/Report  |
|   PD     | Personal Development |             |
```

That's the result of the sorting

```
Explanation :
```

I will try to explain the sorting. At first we look at the formcode. it will put PY on the first row. After that, there will be the row where MenuPath was PY (sort by alphabeth on the description). In this case EmployeeBank show first. If it doesn't have any child path, the next row will be EmployeeData. after that, EmployeeData has a child like we could see there's Bonus Component(sort by Description) on the next row. After that, if it doesn't have any child, the next row will be Tax Result, but as you can see, Bonus Component still has a child (Bonus by Cost Centre and FinalBonus) so this 2 data will appear after Bonus Component. Tax Result will appear next. The process will keep like that until the end of data.

Sorry if my english messed up and my explanation not good at all. If anyone understand what I mean and could fix my english on the explanation please do it

Thanks for the help

Comment: What is the logic? Which ones come first? It is not alphabetical and we don't know what column defines the sort order.

Comment: I am not getting the logic for this sorting .. please define ..

Comment: :) If you dont know the condition of sort, 15 select queries with conditions of each row, unioned will give you the expected output

Comment: do you have the order pre-defined in a table? you want to select items based on that order?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543771/sql-query-with-specific-order-by-format/17543847#17543847

Comment: sorry I will try to add the logic

Comment: I would use a word like "hierarchy" to indicate that you want "child" items (as defined by their `MenuPath`) to appear alphabetically sorted below their "parents"

Comment: Create separate table for all possible MenuPath values (including empty one), assign them correct sequence number (you may skip some numbers to simplify making future changes - like PY=10, PY/ED=20 etc). For your query, link to this table, order by sequence number and by formcode.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no logic to sort in a way in which you have shown us ..however you can achieve so by assigning some kind of ID to your field and then sort on it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
ORDER BY CASE [FormCode]
WHEN 'PY' THEN 1
WHEN 'EM' THEN 2
WHEN 'EB' THEN 3
WHEN 'ED' THEN 4
WHEN 'Bonus' THEN 5
WHEN 'BonusbyCC' THEN 6
WHEN 'FinalBonus' THEN 7
WHEN 'Tax' THEN 8
WHEN 'Preference' THEN 9
WHEN 'Period' THEN 10
WHEN 'Process' THEN 11
WHEN 'Annual' THEN 12
WHEN 'Report' THEN 13
WHEN 'Badge' THEN 14
WHEN 'PD' THEN 15
END;
```

**[SAMPLE FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7e5c46/2)**

Comment: Thanks for answering...actually the problem is there's 600 row of data that need to be sort

Comment: Agreed. So do you have any constraints for sorting?

Comment: I have some explanation about the logic sorting on my question..look at it sir..thanks